# How can I optimize active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

When I use [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) with tables that have 5000+ records in them everything becomes very slow. How I can optimise it? Does anybody know some plugins which would allow me to load the data asynchronously?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do.

By default, Active Admin loads associations as drop-down filters on the index page. If those filters aren't being used, it helps to remove them because they instantiate every record of that model to build the drop-down.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  remove_filter :categories
end
```

If your index page has columns that depend on associated records, it helps to eager-load them.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.includes :author, :publisher
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't really apply since you only have 5000 records, but if you get to the point where even a DB `COUNT` of the table takes a long time, you might want to disable the count in the bottom right of the index page. (this feature was added in 0.6.1)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index pagination_total: false
end
```

Comment: Would it be much faster to set the filter to something like `filter :association, as: :select, collection: -> { Association.pluck :id }`... as opposed to instantiating a Ruby object for each `association` row as is the default when you `filter :association` unconditionally?

Comment: Yes, that would help a lot. But you'd need to be sure to pass a human-friendly name back as well. For example: `Author.pluck(:name, :id)`