# How can I filter ActiveAdmin index listings by a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

Let's say I have a table `posts`, and another table `reviews` that has a `post_id` and a `rating` (integer).

How can I add a filter to `app/admin/post.rb` which returns posts with a certain total score? (e.g. SUM(reviews.rating) GROUP BY (posts.id)). I want the filter to show up on the right side of the index, along with the other filters, and ideally to function as a range input.

To be clear, when I say "filter", I mean the ActiveAdmin `filter` method which adds filters to the right sidebar on the index page.

I created a scope in `Post` which returns posts with scores, but I haven't been able to find a way to use that in an ActiveAdmin filter.

Note: I rewrote my example because my original one didn't capture the complexity of the question.

Comment: I'm confused; do you want to perform these queries as a filter, a scope, or both?

Comment: The end goal is to be able to filter on the calculated value from the posts index page. I wrote a scope because I wanted to make sure the query was correct and I thought that would be a flexible and easy way to add it to ActiveAdmin. So far, however, I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/70

Answer (score 3):

It's [common to override `scoped_collection` to join associated records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667689#19667689) to increase performance:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.includes :author, :publisher
    end
  end
end
```

Since the entire collection now has author and publisher included, you can have a scope that queries those:

```
scope :random_house do |scope|
  scope.where publishers: {name: 'Random House'}
end
```

Comment: That certainly looks useful, but I still don't know how to add a filter using that scope. 

I was hoping for something like `filter scope: :random_house, as: :checkbox`.

Comment: Although in my case it's even trickier, because my value is calculated so I need Ransack to generate `HAVING SUM(reviews.rating) > 100` or something like that (instead of using WHERE). That's why I was hoping to use a scope that I already wrote rather than having to figure out how to get Ransack to generate complex SQL.

Comment: The `filter scope: :random_house, as: :checkbox` would be better written as a select box to choose from different publishers. For example: `filter :publisher_name, as: :select, collection: ->{Publisher.uniq.pluck :name}`

Comment: Agreed - for your example that would be fine. But the reason I wanted it to work on scopes is so it would be possible to query on SQL aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't come up with a proper solution to this question, but I have found a workaround.

I can change the scoped_collection based on a query param, and simply pass the param in when I want to use it. For example, if I have a scope with_rating(x), which returns posts with a score of at least x, I can write:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    if params[:with_rating]
      super.with_rating(params[:with_rating])
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Then I can go to `/admin/posts?with_rating=100` and get back posts with a rating of at least 100.

Thanks to @seanlinsley for making me aware of the `scoped_collection` method that I used in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use counter cache column to store the comments count

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Then the column will get updated each time a comment is created to that post.This would also help in increasing the performance of search.

Comment: Thanks. The situation is actually more complicated than the example I gave, so a counter cache won't work. I was trying to keep it simple, but apparently I made the example too simple :) I've updated my question to explain that. Do you know a way to query directly on join models / scopes?