# how do I make active admin load faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

on heroku, my active admin Report model page loads very slowly and usually just times out. I found the culprit:

```
Interaction Load (114.0ms)  SELECT "interactions".* FROM "interactions"
FbUser Load (66.5ms)  SELECT "fb_users".* FROM "fb_users"
```

How do I make this page load faster with active admin?

Comment: What do you mean, "the culprit"? 114.0 **milliseconds** is hardly going top make the page timeout. Both the queries you've posted account for less two tenths of a second combined.

Comment: @meagar: depends on timeout value, though :)

Comment: Hmm, I would be surprised if it's the DB time causing timeout.  Are you running a full instance on Heroku or a development (free one).  The main issue that I've found with active_admin is that it basically fires up a second rails app as an engine and that takes some time on first request.  After that it should be ok....

Comment: Compared to the other models that load, which take just a few ms, this takes a lot longer. I am using a free instance of heroku right now, so maybe that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, the solution is very simple:

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do

  remove_filter :interactions
  remove_filter :fb_user

end
```

For more performance tips, see: [How can I optimize active_admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655580/how-i-can-optimize-active-admin/19667689#19667689)